# convert string to int make app stopped unexpectedly

Tags: android

I'm new in eclipse and I have got a project that can add and edit name , age , etc using a textview maybe same like a contacts list

in here i have 3 class.. 1 for arraylist data 1 for view holder and the last is my activity
the problem is when i use a parseint for the age.. if i using string there is no any problem
when i using a `parseint` and after i fill in name and age and press add button it show me the application has stopped unexpectedly..

this is some of the code

```
public void Save(View view){
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

        ArrayAdapter<Data> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Data>)getListAdapter();

        EditText Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Name);
        EditText Age = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Age);

        String name = Name.getText().toString();
        int age = Integer.parseInt(Age.getText().toString());

        if (edit)
        {
            Data temp = adapter.getItem(position);
            temp.setData(name,age);
        }
        else
        {
            Data temp = new Data(name, age);
            friends.add(temp);
        }
        viewflipper.showNext();
    }
```

that `int age = Integer.parseInt(Age.getText().toString());` i don't know whats wrong with that code if i use string its work and i have already change my xml for my textview to this 
`android:inputType="number" >` but it also same error

this is the logcat

```
06-15 08:25:56.419: W/KeyCharacterMap(6003): No keyboard for id 0
06-15 08:25:56.419: W/KeyCharacterMap(6003): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
06-15 08:25:58.619: W/ResourceType(6003): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x0000000c
06-15 08:25:58.619: D/AndroidRuntime(6003): Shutting down VM
06-15 08:25:58.629: W/dalvikvm(6003): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
06-15 08:25:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(6003): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-15 08:25:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(6003): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xc
06-15 08:25:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
06-15 08:25:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2857)
06-15 08:25:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at itnb.week.Exercise6Activity$DataAdapter.getView(Exercise6Activity.java:165)
06-15 08:25:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
06-15 08:25:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1216)
06-15 08:25:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1127)
06-15 08:25:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
06-15 08:25:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
06-15 08:25:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
06-15 08:25:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
06-15 08:25:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
06-15 08:25:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
06-15 08:25:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
06-15 08:25:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
06-15 08:25:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
06-15 08:25:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
06-15 08:25:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
06-15 08:25:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
06-15 08:25:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
06-15 08:25:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
06-15 08:25:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
06-15 08:25:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-15 08:25:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-15 08:25:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-15 08:25:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-15 08:25:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-15 08:25:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-15 08:25:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-15 08:25:58.650: E/AndroidRuntime(6003):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You may have added a space in the end while supplying the number as input in the edittext.

Comment: where is line 165 in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
 textview.setText(Integer.toString(age));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you tried to set the text as an int. I mean you tried `textview.setText(age);`

So you have to use String, like `textview.setText(" "+age);`

Comment: @ Samir we can set as textview.setText(Integer.toString(age));
instead of adding extra space?

Comment: @imran yes, either should work, because Java does `Integer.toString()` under the hood when it passes the + operator on a String and an int.